# Is there any way to update whole Entity in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using Spring Data MongoDB and currently I'm wondering if there's any way to update whole entity like mongoTemplate.update(entityObject)? Because the usual way is to update properties one-by-one.. 
P.S. Code written in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the save() method on the entity.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%7B%7Bsave%28%29%7D%7Dinthemongoshell

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+-+Saving+Objects+Using+DBObject

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me :) Didn't know that saving in MongoDB works that way :)

Comment: is there an equivalent for the new 3 java driver?

Answer (score 1):

Right - the save() method does a full document replace. Because the database is schema-less, the concept of fields doesn't really exist apart from your document.